# VBA EXCEL for each cell in range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

how to move to next cell without doing anything if condition is not met

```
For Each Cel In Range("F22:F3000")
If IsEmpty(Cel.Value) = True Or Not IsDate(Cel.Value) Then
End If
Next Cel
If DateAdd("m", 2, Cel.Value) = Date Then
'Cel.Row(sRow).Select
ws_1.Rows(Cel.Row).EntireRow.Copy ws_2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
notify.Toast "My Title", "Message"
MsgBox "regarder la colonne Annotation", vbExclamation
End If
Next
```

error of compilation next without for

Comment: You have 2 `Next` statements. Remove the one that is not in the right place. - this one: `Next Cel`

Comment: add [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) as the first line in your vba module (always!) and then try running it.  It will give errors on any undeclared variables and most invalid syntax. Fix those issues and your problem should become more clear.

Comment: also helpful - indenting your code! On this page (https://www.automateexcel.com/vba-code-indenter/) you can do it automatically for VBA code and you you can easily sport the who "next" statements

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be a beginner, let me show you how your code might look like, corrected and indented:

```
For Each Cel In Range("F22:F3000")
  If IsEmpty(Cel.Value) = True Or Not IsDate(Cel.Value) Then
  End If

  If DateAdd("m", 2, Cel.Value) = Date Then
    'Cel.Row(sRow).Select
    ws_1.Rows(Cel.Row).EntireRow.Copy ws_2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) notify.Toast "My Title", "Message"
    MsgBox "regarder la colonne Annotation", vbExclamation
  End If
Next Cel
```

As you see, I have removed the first `Next Cel`, you only can have one `Next` in a `For`-loop.